# How to execute code after sending HttpResponse

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I currently evaluate if we should switch our application from using Tomcat to akka-http. In tomcat we could send the http response by setting the status on a HttpServletResponse object and write the response body to its PrintWriter, do flush() and execute arbitrary (possible long running) code afterwards (e.g. persist the request body). So the latency for that request was independent of the code that came after flushing the response.

Is it possible to achieve the same with akka-http (Akka Version 2.4.9)?

I know that there is the completeWithFuture(java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage value) directive in Akka's Routing DSL, but as far as I know all CompletionStages will be executed before sending the response.

Comment: Unsure about the directives, but You can schdule the sending of a message to a worker actor in the worst case, no?

Comment: @Diego in akka-http a request handler or a flow must be used to provide a http response for each http request like this:  `Http.get(system).bindAndHandle(handler, ConnectHttp.toHost("127.0.0.1", 8080), materializer);`. That flow or handler is essentially a function (request->response). I can not think of a way to answer the request with a worker actor in the current version of akka-http.

Comment: Not to answer the request, to do whatever you need to do after you answer it. You still have a system somewhere, right? You can do scheduleMessage; respond; , and then the timer will trigger and spawn the worker with wever you need to do. Probably not the cleanest way, but it's a worst case fix.

Comment: Your are right. I'm going to do that as a workaround. Still, besides from spreading parts of object logic into actors and making the code less readable, it would not be possible to run tasks that must happen after the request was sent. Simple example: getting the timestamp of when the response has been sent, e.g. for monitoring purposes.

Comment: Unsure. Have you tried simply writing more code after the complete? Does it get executed?

Comment: The handler that has to be passed to the `bindAndHandleXXX` methods is essentially a function that returns a HttpResponse. Only then the response is sent and I can not find a way to execute code afterwards as code after a return statement is unreachable. The same applies to Routing DSL that creates a flow from a Route object that is created by `complete`. After returning that Route object and the response that it contains, there is AFAIK no callback function to run some more code based on the request or other intermediate data.